# Deleting categories in magento

Tags: magento, categories

I want to delete empty categories, using the following code:

```
`<?php
require "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('level',  array('gteq' => 2));
foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
    if ($category->getProductCount() === 0) {
                               print_r ($category);
                           echo "<br><hr><br>";
        $category->delete();
    }
}
echo 'End!';
?>`
```

Upon executing this code, it crashes at delete.

print_r gives the following result:

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object (
[_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category
[_eventObject:protected] => category
[_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category
[_useFlatResource:protected] => 1
[_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array (
[0] => custom_design
[1] => custom_design_from
[2] => custom_design_to
[3] => page_layout
[4] => custom_layout_update
[5] => custom_apply_to_products
)
[_treeModel:protected] =>
[_defaultValues:protected] => Array (
)
[_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array (
)
[_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array (
)
[_isDeleteable:protected] => 1
[_isReadonly:protected] =>
[_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category_flat
[_resource:protected] =>
[_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_flat_collection
[_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
[_isObjectNew:protected] =>
[_data:protected] => Array (
[entity_id] => 53
[level] => 4
[path] => 1/2/27/39/53
[position] => 3
[is_active] => 1
[is_anchor] => 1
[product_count] => 0
)
[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
[_origData:protected] => Array (
[entity_id] => 53
[level] => 4
[path] => 1/2/27/39/53
[position] => 3
[is_active] => 1
[is_anchor] => 1
)
[_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id
[_isDeleted:protected] =>
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array (
)
[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array (
)
)
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
  require "app/Mage.php";
  umask(0);
  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
  $categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('level',  array('gteq' => 2));
foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
   if ($category->getProductCount() === 0) {
       print_r ($category->entity_id);
       echo "<br><hr><br>";
       $category->delete();
    }
}
echo 'End!';
?>
```

You have to add this line

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
```

you write this code print_r ($category); so its reruns the array. That is not error.